# Compiling C++11 code on older versions of gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

We are trying to build a C++ project which was recently modified to mark some destructor as noexcept on a legacy system which uses gcc 4.5.4.

The use of this compiler version is mandatory, so upgrading is not a solution.

The only C++11 feature that is in the code is the noexcept specifier for destructors.

I have read that while 4.5 does not support the standard -std=c++11, it does support the experimental (at the time) flag -std=gnu++0x . However, using this to compile a simple test project that uses the noexcept specifier does not allow the code to compile either. The code for this example is available below.

test.h:

```cpp
class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    ~Test() noexcept;
};
```

test.cpp:

```cpp
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Test::Test()
{
  cout<<"Ctor"<<endl;
}

Test::~Test() noexcept
{
  cout<<"Dtor"<<endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 {
  Test t;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

I guess the experimental flag i used should have been the main solution here, but i wanted to check here if maybe i am missing any alternatives.

If it's just not possible to compile this code using gcc 4.5.4, my solution would be to declare a macro that applies noexcept only under a certain condition which would evaluate to true only on the legacy build system. But i am open to alternatives.

The error i am getting when using this compiler, btw, is:

```sh
# g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp main.cpp -o runme
In file included from test.cpp:1:0:
test.h:5:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘noexcept’
test.cpp:11:15: error: expected initializer before ‘noexcept’
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
test.h:5:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘noexcept’
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-Dnoexcept=` ? That's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: I'd recommend `-Dnoexcept=throw()` instead

Comment: @JerryCoffin may work for this example, but not in general because of noexcept operator.

Comment: @eerorika: at least according to the question, they don't use the noexcept operator, only the noexcept specifier: "The only C++11 feature that is in the code is the noexcept specifier for destructors."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A general solution to writing programs that are portable across dialects of C++, whether that is for different standard versions or for language extensions is to wrap the feature in a macro:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#define NOEXCEPT noexcept
#else
#define NOEXCEPT
#endif

Test::~Test() NOEXCEPT
```

---

However, destructors are implicitly `noexcept` (unless a sub-object has a potentially throwing destructor), so simplest solution in this particular case is to simply remove the `noexcept` declaration, since that won't change the meaning of the program in C++11.

Comment: This is true, however making destructors noexcept came in as a requirement citing this: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-dtor-noexcept

Comment: @andrei note that cpp core guidelines are generally not requirements. It is completely optional to follow the guidelines.

Comment: Thanks, i understand what you mean and i agree, i meant requirements in the literal sense as coming in an explicit form from the client.

Comment: @andrei I see. I suppose that's not the same client that enforces the use of an ancient compiler? Would be rather unfair to impose contradictory requirements.